# Bootstrap correct way to change image for different viewports?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have it working in modern browsers but old browsers that don't support media queries it will display 2 logos.

```
<img src="logo-sm.jpg" class="visible-xs-inline-block" />
<img src="logo.jpg" class="hidden-xs" />
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to add a fallback solution for old browser so that i dont end up with 2 logos

Answer (score 0):

use class img-responsive to make images responsive.

```
<img src="logo-sm.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
```